# Is there any way to truncate when using logical replication in postgresql 10?

Tags: postgresql, replication

Is it possible to clone a truncate in postgresql version 10.1 or 9.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** From v11 on, logical replication can replicate `TRUNCATE`. This answer is only for old, unsupported versions.

---

I assume that 9.2 is a typo, because that old and unsupported release does not have logical replication.

Also, using 10.1 is dangerous. Upgrading to the latest minor release is simple and painless and will fix bugs that can lead to data corruption.

`TRUNCATE` is not replicated by logical replication in v10. So you have to do it yourself on both systems:

- Start a transaction on the primary server.
- `TRUNCATE` the table on the primary and wait until replication for the table has caught up.
- `TRUNCATE` the table on the standby.
- `COMMIT` the transaction on the primary.

Comment: As of postgresql 11+ and indeed now all major supported versions of postgres, replicating TRUNCATE is now supported. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/logical-replication-restrictions.html for details.

Comment: @DB140141 Correct. I have updated the answer.